# Telling AutoMapper to convert from ObjectList property to list of just the Ids

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, automapper

I have a GetUserById function that returns a User. The User has a Roles property which is an object list of Roles.
**Role class looks like this:**

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public int Name { get; set; }
```

In my MVC UI I have a UserViewModel that has a property List RoleIds since all the view needs to now about is the Role Ids to select the appropriate values in my MultiSelect.

When I use AutoMapper to convert from User to UserViewModel how can I specify that I want to take all of the Ids from User.Roles and put them in UserViewModel.RoleIds in the mapping settings.

Answer (score 1):

Was able to achieve this with the following:

```
CreateMap<User, UserViewModel>()
            .ForMember(vm => vm.RoleIds, opt => opt.MapFrom(u => u.Roles.Select(r => r.Id)));
```